# What is the difference between [[]]*4 and [[],[],[],[]]

Tags: python

I create two lists that seems the same

```
x = [[]]*4
y = [[],[],[],[]]
```

since when I `print x, y`, they give me the same output `[[],[],[],[]]`. However, when I apply the same operation `x[0].append((1,2)), y[0].append((1,2))` on them, they give me different result

```
print x  >> [[(1, 2)], [(1, 2)], [(1, 2)], [(1, 2)]]
print y  >> [[(1, 2)], [], [], []]
```

Why this happens? And how to modify `x` to make sure `x` and `y` are exactly the same?

Comment: Short answer: [[]] creates 4 references to the same list. See Michael0x2a's link for a longer answer.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: `[[] for x in range(4)]`

Comment: Great! this solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is a list that references 4 times the same list.

`y` is a list of 4 independent empty lists.